# Jobs jumps from RUNNING to PREP state

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

When I run a mapreduce job, it jumps from `RUNNING` to `PREP` state. I have looked to the mapreduce logs and I haven't found any exception. I am wondering if this is a problem related to the yarn configuration. So, I have looked to the configuration of the `mapred-site.xml` [2], and it seems that the memory size is correct. I am running in a PC with 16 cores and 64GB of RAM, although I have set mapreduce to run with 32GB (`<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name> <value>32218</value>`). Any suggestion to try to debug this?

[1] Job status

```
Total jobs:1
                  JobId      State           StartTime      UserName           Queue      Priority       UsedContainers  RsvdContainers  UsedMem         RsvdMem        NeededMem          AM info
 job_1379101056979_0001       PREP       1379101096477          root         default        NORMAL                    0               0       0M              0M
```

[2] `mapred-site.xml`

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
 <property> <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name> <value>yarn</value> </property>
 <property> <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.done-dir</name> <value>/root/Programs/hadoop/logs/history/done</value> </property>
 <property> <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.intermediate-done-dir</name> <value>/root/Programs/hadoop/logs/history/intermediate-done-dir</value> </property>
 <property> <name>mapreduce.job.reduces</name> <value>4</value> </property>

 <!-- property> <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name> <value>8240</value> </property -->
 <property> <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name> <value>24240</value> </property>
 <property> <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name> <value>1024</value> </property>

<!-- property><name>mapreduce.task.files.preserve.failedtasks</name><value>true</value></property>
<property><name>mapreduce.task.files.preserve.filepattern</name><value>*</value></property -->

</configuration>
```

I don't know what is happening to this, so I post here part the log of a job. I notice that the container where the job is running got a `CONTAINER_STOP` signal. Anyone can help me what is going on?

```
2016-10-17 09:57:23,233 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Stopping container with container Id: container_1476697963637_0001_01_000022
2016-10-17 09:57:23,233 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=ubuntu       IP=172.30.0.231 OPERATION=Stop Container Request        TARGET=ContainerManageImpl      RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1476697963637_0001    CONTAINERID=container_1476697963637_0001_01_000022
2016-10-17 09:57:23,263 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_1476697963637_0001_01_000020 transitioned from KILLING to CONTAINER_CLEANEDUP_AFTER_KILL
2016-10-17 09:57:23,263 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_1476697963637_0001_01_000022 transitioned from RUNNING to KILLING
2016-10-17 09:57:23,321 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Cleaning up container container_1476697963637_0001_01_000022
2016-10-17 09:57:23,341 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting absolute path : /home/ubuntu/tmp/hadoop-temp/nm-local-dir/usercache/ubuntu/appcache/application_1476697963637_0001/container_1476697963637_0001_01_000020
2016-10-17 09:57:23,404 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 27978 for container-id container_1476697963637_0001_01_000042: 263.0 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.8 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
2016-10-17 09:57:23,559 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=ubuntu       OPERATION=Container Finished - Killed   TARGET=ContainerImpl    RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1476697963637_0001    CONTAINERID=container_1476697963637_0001_01_000020
2016-10-17 09:57:23,559 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_1476697963637_0001_01_000020 transitioned from CONTAINER_CLEANEDUP_AFTER_KILL to DONE
2016-10-17 09:57:23,559 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.Application: Removing container_1476697963637_0001_01_000020 from application application_1476697963637_0001
2016-10-17 09:57:23,559 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.AppLogAggregatorImpl: Considering container container_1476697963637_0001_01_000020 for log-aggregation
2016-10-17 09:57:23,559 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event CONTAINER_STOP for appId application_1476697963637_0001
2016-10-17 09:57:23,570 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Exit code from container container_1476697963637_0001_01_000022 is : 143
2016-10-17 09:57:23,571 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_1476697963637_0001_01_000022 transitioned from KILLING to CONTAINER_CLEANEDUP_AFTER_KILL
2016-10-17 09:57:23,571 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting absolute path : /home/ubuntu/tmp/hadoop-temp/nm-local-dir/usercache/ubuntu/appcache/application_1476697963637_0001/container_1476697963637_0001_01_000022
2016-10-17 09:57:23,572 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=ubuntu       OPERATION=Container Finished - Killed   TARGET=ContainerImpl    RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1476697963637_0001    CONTAINERID=container_1476697963637_0001_01_000022
2016-10-17 09:57:23,572 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_1476697963637_0001_01_000022 transitioned from CONTAINER_CLEANEDUP_AFTER_KILL to DONE
2016-10-17 09:57:23,572 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.Application: Removing container_1476697963637_0001_01_000022 from application application_1476697963637_0001
2016-10-17 09:57:23,572 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.AppLogAggregatorImpl: Considering container container_1476697963637_0001_01_000022 for log-aggregation
2016-10-17 09:57:23,572 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event CONTAINER_STOP for appId application_1476697963637_0001
2016-10-17 09:57:23,670 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 27820 for container-id container_1476697963637_0001_01_000040: 266.3 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.8 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
```

Comment: would you please post log portion corresponding to when this transition happens?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue; restarting cloudera and yarn solved it.

If restarting doesn't work, try checking the ports in `job.properties` - there might be a problem with the `namenode` and `jobtracker` ports. Make sure your `jobtracker` port is correct in the `job.properties` file.

Also check map-reduce cluster slots. It might be running out of slots.